# Making Object Instances using a while loop

Tags: java, class, object, multiple-instances

I'm making a program to simulate patients and the severity of their illness.

I'm having trouble with adding different instances of one class to another class.

For some reason, when I use a while loop, it ultimately only makes one instance.

Here is my code:

```
 while(myScan.hasNext()){

      String line = myScan.nextLine();
      String [] storage = line.split(",");
      int severity = Integer.parseInt(storage[1]);

      Patient x = new Patient(storage[0],severity);
      Priority.add(x);

      }
```

When I make each instance separately and print my "Priority" class, it works fine.  But when using the while loop, it only prints out the last instance, as if it is getting overwritten.

For Example:

```
Patient p1 = new Patient(name1,1);
Patient p2 = new Patient(name2,2);
Patient p3 = new Patient(name3,3);
```

This will work fine. but not when using the while loop to read from a file.
It will only print p3.

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, OP please add a lang tag. Also where is `Priority` declared?

Comment: so Priority has static method add?

Comment: you have to post `Priority class` in your question

Comment: I dont want to post Priority because it will probably confuse you guys.  It is a binary heap that I made from scratch. It has a variable called last position which starts at zero. Everytime something is added, it adds one. Example: lastPosition++;

Answer (score 0):

I cant see Priority defined as a storage (array/linkedList). So you need create variable to store Patient instances of the data.

```
ArrayList<Patient> items = new ArrayList<Patient>();
while(myScan.hasNext()){

  String line = myScan.nextLine();
  String [] storage = line.split(",");
  int severity = Integer.parseInt(storage[1]);

  Patient x = new Patient(storage[0],severity);
  items.add(x);

  }
```

Now items should contain created patients.
I hope it is Java :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are not iterating over your structure.
You are just using the same Patient x over and over again.

You should use Lists or a Patient-Array to create your different Patients.
Or do you use Priority for that? If yes you should be able to get your different Patients out of this "List".

Edit: Example:

```
LinkedList<Patient> listOfPatients = new LinkedList<>();
while(myScan.hasNext){
    .
    .
    .
    Patient x = ... ;
    listOfPatients.add(x);
}
Patient p1=listOfPatients.getAt(0);
Patient p2=listOfPatients.getAt(1);
.
.
.
```

Just a simple example. I hope it helps.

Comment: as i read your comment above: i think your Priority-Class does not store your Objects correctly. The instances were created - for sure, but they haven't been stored this far. You can try the LinkedList-Version i showed to test.